# Is there a way to remove all node_modules on a system and replace them with pnpm cache?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, pnpm

So node_modules have taken all the space on my drive now. What I  want to achieve is delete all node_modules on my system and replace them what pnpm does i.e. a single cache for those dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For removing node_modules you can you this tool called [npkill](https://npkill.js.org/). Then when you'll work on some project, just run `pnpm install`. pnpm does not have a feature to scan all directories in search of node_modules, remove and reinstall them automatically.

Comment: Someone should make a such a library then I guess.